# Need to retrieve data from a PC HDD which won't boot

Tags: hard-drive, boot, desktop-computer

I have a Hitachi SATA 500GB HardDrive, which was removed from my PC because it doesnot boot the OS. It just hangs at the loading screen. The thing is I have a whole lot of data,software,some movies and one or two series I really enjoy and some music in there that I would lie to retrieve. How can I do this ??? I spend a LOT of man hours working on some projects using those s/w and downloading . So help please........

PS: I tried to reinstall the OS but even then the HDD would not be detected.......... :/

Comment: Have you tried booting from a live-CD or bootable USB stick, so that you can access the HDD that way?

Comment: 5pike is correct you either use a boot CD and inspect that HD (hopefully its not damaged and your data is still available) or your take the HD out and place in another machine...

Answer (score 0):

Unmount your HDD from PC and connect it by external way with other pc through usb cable.

Moreover you need to boot other PC HDD as Main in BIOS and another device your problem HDD as second HDD

Answer (score 0):

If you have two harddrive's you could simply install windows on the other "new" harddrive, and then set your 500GB HardDrive as a slave drive.

Then you will set the new hard drive as your boot option, and after you get into window's you will have full access to your 500GB hard drive!

This is because the 500gb would no longer be trying to boot windows, and would instead act just like a normal hard drive that you might use to store data on.